# MVC 4 Foreign Key Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model with 2 fields that have a foreign key connection to a different table. They have different names and I can't figure out how to make the relationship work.

Here are my two objects. The `Visitor` and `Home Teams` are what I'm having trouble setting up the relationship between.

The error I'm getting is:

> "Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Models.Game'. The
>   ForeignKeyAttribute on property VisitorID on Type 'Models.Game' is not
>   valid. The navigation property 'Team' was not found on the dependent
>   type 'Models.Game'. Name value should be a valid navigation property
>   name."

```
public class Team
{
    public Int64 TeamID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Team Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "League Name")]
    [ForeignKey("League")]
    public Int64 LeagueID { get; set; }

    public virtual League League { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public Int64 GameID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Season Name")]
    [ForeignKey("Season")]
    public Int64 SeasonID { get; set; }

    public virtual Season Season { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Game Time")]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Visitor Team")]
    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    public Int64 VisitorID { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Visitor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Home Team")]
    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    public Int64 HomeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Home { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Rink")]
    [ForeignKey("Location")]
    public Int64 LocationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    public virtual List<GameEvent> GameEvents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? & Why are your primary keys a mix of 32bit integers and 64bit?

Comment: it would be helpful if you remove all the extra code and data annotations that aren't necessary so its easier for us to read (like the `required` and `display`)

Answer (score 0):

Change your FK attribute. It must contain navigation property name, not type

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Visitor Team")]
    [ForeignKey("Visitor")]
    public Int64 VisitorID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of research I found out what I was doing wrong in the Game model. Martin was correct in stating that I needed to use the navigation property. I also needed to put the [ForeignKey] attribute on the reference property and not the ID. I've listed the corrected code below for the Visitor and Home Teams

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Visitor Team")]               
    public Int64 VisitorID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VisitorID")]
    public virtual Team Visitor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Home Team")]        
    public Int64 HomeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomeID")]
    public virtual Team Home { get; set; }
```